# javascript. after ajax complete function, the 'a' is not clickable anymore, why?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i have again a small question. 
i am using ajax and working fine. but after the ajax did his job i want to change the element atttibutes like backgroundImage. it is also working fine. but the changed element is now not clickable anymore for the second time.. can someone help me please.. 
here is my code:

```
function ajaxdelete(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxdelete/",
        }).complete(function(){
            kids = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName('td');
            for (var i=0; i < kids.length; i++) {
              kids[i].style.backgroundImage = "none";
            };


        });


    }
```

and my html is this:

```
<td style="background-image: url("../static/images/ok.png");"><a onclick="postajax1()"><input type="hidden" name="arg1" value="10"/><input type="hidden" name="arg2" value="3"/>0,24*</a></td>
```

so after ajax call, the background must be clean again, and the 'a' tag must be clickable again for the 2nd time also.. in other words, the postajax1() function must be callable and be able to set the background image again back to initial state.

please help!

many thanks..

Comment: You should not nest input elements inside link - and you should reproduce the error in a fiddle

Comment: yeah, you are right.. i corrected it. but the problem was in my another ajax function which was setting onclick=false. now it is working, fine fine, many thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using Jquery to target your  with class name?

`function ajaxdelete(){`

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajaxdelete/",
    }).complete(function(){
        kids = $('#table1 td.className');
        kids.css('background-image','none');
    });
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, this is also more elegant solution, Zaw. cool, i like it.